# Linq - left join on multiple (OR) conditions

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I need to do a left join on multiple conditions where the conditions are `OR`s rather than `AND`s.  I've found lots of samples of the latter but am struggling to get the right answer for my scenario.

```
from a in tablea
join b in tableb on new { a.col1, a.col2 } equals new { b.col1, b.col2 }
group a by a into g
select new () { col1 = a.col1, col2 = a.col2, count = g.Count() }
```

works great for joins where all conditions must match.  I need to get the join to match `on a.col1 = b.col1 OR a.col2 = b.col2`.

I know it must be easy but I've coming up blank on this!

Edit:

To give a little more info, the purpose of the query is to get a projection containing all of the fields from 'a' plus a count of the matching records in 'b'.  I've amended the sample above to try and illustrate what I'm after.  When I run with the above using the approach Jon Skeet has noted I'm getting a count of all records from a, not the count of the related records in b.

The basic left join works fine:

```
from a in tablea
from b in tableb
.Where( b => ( a.col1 == b.col1 || a.col2 == b.col2))
.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { col1 = a.col1, col2 = a.col2 }
```

If I revise it to add the grouping as below

```
from a in tablea
from b in tableb
.Where( b => ( a.col1 == b.col1 || a.col2 == b.col2))
.DefaultIfEmpty()
group a by a.col1 into g
select new { col1 = g.Key, count = g.Count() }
```

I'm getting the count of the records returned from a - not the count of records in matching in b.

Edit:

I'll give the answer to Jon - I've solved my count issue - I hadn't realized I could use a lamda to filter the count `(g.Count(x => x != null))`.  Plus I need to group b by a rather than a by a as I had above. This gives the correct result but the SQL is not as efficient as I'd write it by hand as it adds a correlated sub query - if anyone can advise a better way of writing it to simulate the following SQL I'd appreciate it!

```
select a.col1, count(b.col1)
from tablea a
left join tableb b
on a.col1 = b.col1
or a.col2 = b.col2
group by a.col1
```

Comment: I suggest you try my query *without* the grouping, and see whether that's getting the results you expect. If it does, then try to work out why the grouping is failing. Perhaps group by `new { a.col1, a.col2 }`?

Comment: Works fine as a basic left join select - getting the count out of the grouping is not behaving as I'd expect it to if this were a basic equi-join. Note the extra info above.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

LINQ only directly supports equijoins. If you want to do any other kind of join, you basically need a cross-join and `where`:

```
from a in tablea
from b in tableb
where a.col1 == b.col1 || a.col2 == b.col2
select ...
```

It's probably worth checking what the generated SQL looks like and what the query plan is like. There may be more efficient ways of doing it, but this is probably the *simplest* approach.

Comment: I've started with this approach... I'm actually grouping in the query proper to get all records from a and the count of matching records from b.  I'll edit the post to clarify.

Answer (score 21):

Depending on the query provider, you could just choose to use two from clauses:

```
from a in tablea
from b in tableb 
where a.col1 == b.col1 || a.col2 == b.col2
```

Which, if you execute on a DB, will be just as efficient.  If you execute in-memory (Linq to Objects), this will enumerate all possible combinations, which may be inefficient.

Arg, Skeeted ;-).

More efficient Linq to Objects alternatives are possible.  The `join` operator enumerates each source only once, and then does a hash-join, so you could split the or-clause into two seperate joins, and then take their union.  A union in linq is just a concatenation without duplicates, so that would look as follows:

```
(from a in tablea
join b in tableb on a.Col1 equals b.Col1
select new {a, b})
.Concat(
from a in tablea
join b in tableb on a.Col2 equals b.Col2
select new {a, b}
).Distinct()
```

This approach works, and it's just one query, but it's somewhat non-obvious in the sense that the performance characteristics of the code depend on understanding in detail how linq works.  Personally, if you want to do a hash-join with potentially multiple matches, a more obvious tool is `ToLookup`.  An alternative using that might look as follows:

```
var bBy1 = tableb.ToLookup(b=>b.Col1);
var bBy2 = tableb.ToLookup(b=>b.Col2);
var q3 = 
    from a in tablea
    from b in bBy1[a.Col1].Concat(bBy2[a.Col2]).Distinct()
    ...
```

This solution is actually shorter, and the reason it works is more obvious, so it's the one I'd prefer.  Just remember that if you split the `||` operator into two separate queries like in the above two scenarios that you need to manually avoid double-counting the results (i.e. use `Distinct`).

Comment: I am using Linq to objects - is there an alternative solution?