# LINQ to SQL complex join with mixed conditions

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I have a SQL statement which I am trying to convert into LINQ to SQL, and I've managed to get most of it converted, but have come across one statement which I can't wrap my head around in LINQ.

The section of the SQL query that's causing the headache is:

```
SELECT *
FROM step
INNER JOIN action on 
    (step.NextAction = action.ID and step.ActionStatus != 4) or 
    (step.ACTION = action.ID and step.ActionStatus = 4)
```

`step` is a table containing a sequence of actions, `action` is the list of actions available. `ActionStatus` is an index into a list of statuses - 4 == 'Failed'.

Basically, for actions which are **not** Failed, it needs to return the **next** action. If the action **has** Failed, it returns the **current** action.

This is just one of the joins (there are a total of 10 tables in the full query), most of them are straight forward equijoins, some on multiple conditions, but I've been able to write them in LINQ with no issue. This one though, I can't see how it would be written.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264993/linq-left-join-on-multiple-or-conditions) answer, but also can't see how to apply that in this scenario. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from s in step
from a in action
where (s.NextAction = a.ID && s.ActionStatus != 4) || (s.Action = a.ID && s.ActionStatus = 4)
select new { Step = s, Action = a };
```

You might want to look at the SQL generated and optimise if needed.

Comment: Is the generated sql looks like yours?