# How to convert following SQL Query into a LINQ to SQL query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have following SQL Query and would like to convert to LINQ to SQL which I will use in entity framework 5.0

```
var internationalDesksList =
            from internationalDesks in _context.InternationalDesks
            from subsection in
                _context.Subsections.Where(
                    s =>
                    internationalDesks.EBALocationId == s.LocationId ||
                    internationalDesks.FELocationId == s.LocationId).DefaultIfEmpty()
            where subsection.PublicationId == 1

            select new {internationalDesks.Id, subsection.LocationId};
```

I have referred the following posts and answers. Though no luck.

- [LINQ to SQL - Left Outer Join with multiple join conditions Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122942/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join-with-multiple-join-conditions)
- [left join on multiple (OR) conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264993/linq-left-join-on-multiple-or-conditions)

When I tried this query in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)  I got the following answer which is correct.

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t1].[Id] AS [Id1]
FROM [InternationalDesks] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Subsection] AS [t1] ON (([t0].[FELocationId]) = [t1].[LocationId]) OR (([t0].[EBALocationId]) = [t1].[LocationId])
WHERE [t1].[PublicationId] = @p0
```

However in entity framework 5 ( DBContext ) it is not providing me with the correct query. When I checked in SQL profiler all columns in subsection table is selected. That's it.

Following is the result:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[PracticeAreaId] AS [PracticeAreaId], 
[Extent1].[LocationId] AS [LocationId], 
...
FROM [dbo].[Subsection] AS [Extent1]
```

Don't know what could be problem. Please help me.

Comment: Please provide LINQ query which you are using

Comment: @lazyberezovsky thanks, I have updated with the LINQ Query.

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ you can't do LEFT OUTER JOIN on some boolean expression, only equijoins are supported. So, you can generate CROSS JOIN this way:

```
var internationalDesksList =
            from internationalDesks in _context.InternationalDesks
            from subsection in _context.Subsections
            where subsection.PublicationId == 1 &&
                  (internationalDesks.EBALocationId == subsection.LocationId ||
                   internationalDesks.FELocationId == subsection.LocationId)
            select new {
                internationalDesks.Id, 
                subsection.LocationId
            };
```

EF 5 will generate following SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent2].[LocationId] AS [LocationId]
FROM  [dbo].[InternationalDesks] AS [Extent1]
CROSS JOIN [dbo].[Subsections] AS [Extent2]
WHERE (1 = [Extent2].[PublicationId]) AND 
      ([Extent1].[EBALocationId] = [Extent2].[LocationId] OR 
       [Extent1].[FELocationId] = [Extent2].[LocationId])
```

As you can see, only required columns are selected. I also checked this query in LINQ to SQL - following query is generated:

```
DECLARE @p0 Int = 1

SELECT [t0].[Id], [t1].[LocationId]
FROM [InternationalDesks] AS [t0], [Subsections] AS [t1]
WHERE ([t1].[PublicationId] = @p0) AND 
      (([t0].[EBALocationId] = [t1].[LocationId]) OR 
       ([t0].[FELocationId] = [t1].[LocationId]))
```

Comment: lazyberezovsky, it adds the condition in where clause where I need them part of left join.
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 223
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t1].[LocationId]
FROM [InternationalDesks] AS [t0], [Subsection] AS [t1]
WHERE ([t1].[PublicationId] = @p0) AND ((([t0].[EBALocationId]) = [t1].[LocationId]) OR (([t0].[FELocationId]) = [t1].[LocationId]))

Comment: @Elangesh you can't have conditions as part of left join. It's impossible to do with LINQ