# How to left join multiple tables with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, join

I'm trying to left join three tables with LINQ.  I have the SQL working as below:

```
Select j.Id, u.FirstName , u.LastName, u.Role
From    Job j  
    left  join JobTranslator as jt on j.Id = jt.JobId
    left  join JobRevisor as jr on j.Id = jr.JobId
    left  join [User] as u on  jt.UserId = u.Id OR jr.UserId = u.Id
Where   u.Id = someID;
```

I can get it to work with two joins like below:

```
 IQueryable<Job> jobs =
                from j in _db.Jobs

                join jr in _db.JobRevisors on j.Id equals jr.JobId into jrs
                from jrResult in jrs.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join u in _db.Users on jrResult.UserId equals u.Id into jrU
                from jrUResult in jrU.DefaultIfEmpty()

                where jrUResult.Id == userId
                orderby j.Id
                select j;
```

But when I try to join my last needed table it doesn't work like below.

```
IQueryable<Job> jobs =
                from j in _db.Jobs

                join jt in _db.JobTranslators on j.Id equals jt.JobId into jts
                from jtResult in jts.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join jr in _db.JobRevisors on jtResult.Id equals jr.JobId into jrs
                from jrResult in jrs.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join u in _db.Users on jrResult.UserId equals u.Id into jrU
                from jrUResult in jrU.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join u in _db.Users on jtResult.UserId equals u.Id into jtU
                from jtUResult in jtU.DefaultIfEmpty()

                where jtUResult.Id == userId

                orderby j.Id

                select j;
```

Any ideas from anyone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Comment: Maybe rename the second `u` to something else?

Comment: What I don't understand is why developers keep insisting on literally translating the SQL to LINQ instead of using navigation properties, collections, and `.Include()`. You generally end up with a more intuitively usable object graph that way.

Comment: include does not help with a left join...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From [Linq - left join on multiple (OR) conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264993/linq-left-join-on-multiple-or-conditions) :

```
IQueryable<Job> jobs = (from j in _db.Jobs

                join jt in _db.JobTranslators on j.Id equals jt.JobId into jts
                from jtResult in jts.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join jr in _db.JobRevisors on jtResult.Id equals jr.JobId into jrs
                from jrResult in jrs.DefaultIfEmpty()


                join u in _db.Users on jtResult.UserId equals u.Id into jtU
                from jtUResult in jtU.DefaultIfEmpty()

                where jtUResult.Id == userId

                orderby j.Id

                select j).Concat(
                from j in _db.Jobs

                join jt in _db.JobTranslators on j.Id equals jt.JobId into jts
                from jtResult in jts.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join jr in _db.JobRevisors on jtResult.Id equals jr.JobId into jrs
                from jrResult in jrs.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join u in _db.Users on jrResult.UserId equals u.Id into jrU
                from jrUResult in jrU.DefaultIfEmpty()

                where jtUResult.Id == userId

                orderby j.Id

                select j
                ).Distinct()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that worked, I had to tweek it a little but the basic concatenate idea worked. Thanks again!

Comment: to be honest, this created the best SQL left join script ef generated i have seen so far