# Entity Framework: How to perform left join with EF and LINQ among multiple tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

basically i have 3 tables and those are `user,colors and usercolor`

### tables info

```
User Tables has fields like -> UserID, UserName

Color Tables has fields like -> ColorID, ColorName

UserColor Tables has fields like -> UserID, ColorID
```

i have corresponding `dbset classes` in my code.

now see the below query where left join is performed among 3 tables in sql and tell me how to write the same equivalent query with EF and LINQ.

```
select c.ColorID
    , c.ColorName
    , IsSelected = case when uc.ColorID is null then 0 else 1 end
from dbo.Colors c
left join dbo.UserColor uc on uc.ColorID = c.ColorID and uc.UserID = 1 --leave this in the join or it becomes an inner join
left join dbo.Users u on u.UserID = uc.UserID
```

Comment: You shouldn't use join in LINQ syntax. Use navigation properties. If you need help with that, please show the class definitions.

Comment: If you really want to do this manually, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37885001/how-to-left-join-multiple-tables-with-linq

Comment: @kiziu as u said it seems various way we can do this things. please discuss if we can solve it various way. thanks

Comment: @GertArnold if u see my table info area then u can understand how class would look like in c# and accordingly just post a sample code to perform join with linq and EF. thanks

Comment: Which part of "You shouldn't use join in LINQ syntax" wasn't clear to you? You've been given it on a plate now, but it's not the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as shown below.

```
var result = from c in dbo.Colors 
             join uc in dbo.UserColor on (uc.ColorID = c.ColorID and uc.UserID = 1) into UserColor
             from q in UserColor.DefaultIfEmpty() join u in dbo.Users 
             on q.UserID equals u.UserID into Users
             from l in Users.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
               {
                 ColorID = c.ColorID,
                 ColorName = c.ColorName,
                 IsSelected = uc.ColorID == null ? 0 : 1
               };
```

You can read more about [**Left Outer Join in LINQ to Entities**](http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/Left-Outer-Join-in-LINQ-to-Entities-(for-Entity-Framework-4).aspx)

Comment: how do i know that left outer join has been used? when we use left outer join then we use left keyword in sql but what keyword is used when we compose the same with EF and LINQ ? how one should be able to know the query is left outer join query compose with EF and LINQ ?

Comment: i will let u know tomorrow after checking your query. thanks

Comment: OK sure.No problem :)

Comment: how to identity linq query that it is left outer join? what special keyword is used to indicate it is left outer join linq query?

Comment: `DefaultIfEmpty()`.you can read more about it using above url too.

Comment: u did not answer for this question "how to identity linq query that it is left outer join? what special keyword is used to indicate it is left outer join linq query?"

Comment: if you see the above query,you can see that,there is a pattern.you have to use that pattern with the `DefaultIfEmpty()` keyword.that is it.no other magic keys here.

Comment: url is now leading to random chrome plugin store page.