# How to join table with itself, with a second "ON" criteria, if a row is null

Tags: sql-server, join, self-join

I have a User table. Among others, it has these 4 columns:

------ `UserID` ------- | ---- `Username` ----- | --- `CreatedBy` --- | `ParentUserID`

(PK, bigint, not null) | (char(20), not null) | (varchar(50), null) | (bigint, null)

---

Both ParentUserID and CreatedBy points at the "owner account", by the UserID or Username respectively. Both are unique.

CreatedBy is never actually `null`, but UserID is indexed, so ParentUserID is preferred - and it's also the one we're moving towards.

Obviously I'm not fluent in SQL, but this is my idea of it:

```
SELECT Users.*
  FROM tblUsers AS Owners
    LEFT JOIN tblUsers AS Users
      ON
        ISNULL(Users.ParentUserID = Owners.UserID,
          Users.CreatedBy = Owners.Username)
    WHERE Owners.UserID = 14;
```

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
SELECT ISNULL(POwners.UserID, COwners.UserID) AS OwnerID, Users.*
  FROM tblUsers AS Users
    RIGHT JOIN tblUsers AS POwners ON Users.ParentUserID = POwners.UserID
    RIGHT JOIN tblUsers AS COwners ON Users.CreatedBy = COwners.Username
WHERE OwnerID = 14;
```

Although obviously this doesn't work. On a secondary note, I further need to convert this to **LINQ**, but for this question, it is only relevant so far that the query will be possible to convert, which I would expect of the vast majority of queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the query that did the trick for me:

```
SELECT Users.*
  FROM tblUsers AS Owners
    LEFT JOIN tblUsers AS Users
      ON Users.ParentUserID = Owners.ParentUserID
        OR Users.CreatedBy = Owners.Username
  WHERE Owners.UserID = 14;
```

Thanks to [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39665691/1380710) for the help.

---

As for LINQ, it turned out [only equijoins are supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1265008/1380710), so I did a cross join like this:

```
from u in dbContext.tblUsers
from o in dbContext.tblUsers
where (u.ParentUserID == o.UserID || u.CreatedBy == o.Username)
    && o.UserID == 14
select u;
```

Which turns into the following query:

```
SELECT Users.*
    FROM  tblUsers AS Users
        CROSS JOIN tblUsers AS Owners
    WHERE(Users.ParentUserID = Owners.UserID OR Users.CreatedBy = Owners.Username)
        AND(Owners.UserID = 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

`join` conditions are just boolean tests, so you need to write a proper boolean condition, e.g. `(P or Q) AND R`. You can't chain them with `,`, so...

```
... ON ISNULL((Users.ParentUserID = Owners.UserID) AND (Users.CreatedBy = Owners.Username))
```

or whatever you need the logic to be. Making it a VALID boolean expression is the critical part.

Comment: I was using the [`ISNULL(a, b)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) because I was under the impression that it uses the second value if the first is `null`. Similar to the null-coalescing operator in C#: `var user = firstUser ?? secondUser;` By the way you've expressed it, It should read something like `Users.ParentUserID = Owners.UserID OR
          Users.CreatedBy = Owners.Username`

Comment: can't you just have `on (a=b) or (c=d)`?

Comment: Yeah, that's a valid expression - and returns the right number of rows. But I don't know if it's right, nor do I know how to verify it. Does it return the row if the first condition is true, without checking the second condition?

Comment: If you want to verify it you can always compare the results with the query I posted ;-)